# unused import statement java string

Tags: java, android-studio, import

i started to work in android studio and i cant understand why i cant import java.lang.String  when i try to import in my mainactivity its says unused import statement. somebody have idea to figure it out? also i tried optimize import and invalidate cache.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import java.lang.String;
```

i really dont know if this is a problem with the android studio or i do something wrong...

Comment: You don't need to import `java.lang.String`, it's available without the import. --- You can delete the line to fix the problem.

Comment: Why are you writing your own imports? Android studio is an IDE; you should be able to let it manage imports for you.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the `java.lang` package can be used without an import statement.

The message "unused import statement" is only a warning and can be ignored, it won't cause the compilation to fail.